# Can't save email to South African S3 bucket using SES email receiving with

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ses

I have attempted now to use Amazon SES email receiving to send the email file to an S3 bucket located in the af-south-1 region of AWS.

It keeps giving me the error of "Server-side message: Unable to write to S3 bucket"

I have also configured my S3 bucket with the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowSESPuts",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "ses.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "AWS:SourceAccount": "Myaccountnumber",
                    "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:ses:eu-west-1:Myaccountnumber:receipt-rule-set/my-rule-set:receipt-rule/my-rule-receipt"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Please can someone advise me on how to move forward?

Comment: Do you have server side encryption enabled on the bucket?

Comment: Here's another way for declaring the policy: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ses-receive-inbound-emails/

Comment: No I do not have any server-side encryption

Comment: I have also tried the way mentioned in the link you sent and I received the same error

Comment: Just a quick note the SES region is in the eu-west-1 region and my bucket is in the af-south-1 region

Comment: You ever find a solution for this? I have the exact same issue.

Comment: The only way we managed to "fix" this, for now, is to receive the email in "eu-west-1" and then use a lambda trigger to copy it over to "af-south-1". Definitely not ideal, but it's a workaround that does the job.